# Hide specific x-axis tick label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm interested in having more space added between the last scatter point and the Y2 (right) spine, rather than having the point immediately adjacent to the spine (see attached PNG [image]).

I can add the desired space by adding a year to the plt.ticks command but then "2017" is displayed which I don't want.

Is there a way to either (a) add space between the last scatter point and the spine using an existing command or (b) use the approach I attempted and hide or make the last label match the background color, or (c) since I'm new to matplotlib and I'm not familiar with all of the terminology, direct me to an existing link?

Thanks in advance.

```
plt.xticks(["1975-01-01", "1980-01-01", "1985-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1995-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2017-01-01"])
```

Comment: do you want to increase the limit of your `x-axis`?

Comment: No, in the end I just more space between the spine and my last point.

Answer (score 1):

I find that using `datetime` objects gives ticks in the right place without modifying `plt.ticks` directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# A few example data points
dates = ['1979-04-3', '1990-05-06', '2000-12-12', '2015-04-20']
dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates]
y = [200, 315, 401, 513]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(dates, y, 'd')
ax.set_ylim(0,800)

# set the x-axis limits explicitly, using datetime objects
xmin = datetime.strptime('1975-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
xmax = datetime.strptime('2017-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

plt.show()
```

If you do need finer control over the x-ticks, you could set them to the years 1975-2015 (inclusive) in 5-year intervals with:

```
ax.set_xticks([datetime.strptime(str(y), '%Y') for y in range(1975,2020,5)])
```

[image]

Comment: Well you might not be calling `plt.xticks`, but you still modify the ticks via `ax.set_xticks`.

Comment: @hitzg That's true, but I found that Matplotlib did a decent job of setting up the axes by itself without either command for the sample data I gave it. OP might need to set the xticks depending on what their data looks like.

Comment: @hitzg,  Your suggestion of ax.set_xticks led to the solution.  I added "2016-01-01" to the ax.set ticks command which gave me the space I wanted between the last point and the right spine.  I followed that with the  ax.set_xticks assigning it " " (haven't figure out new line).  ax.set_xticks(["1975-01-01", "1980-01-01", "1985-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1995-01-01", 
               "2000-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01"])
ax.set_xticklabels(["1975", "1980", "1985", "1990", "1995", 
               "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", " "])